# Настройка иконок классов IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

Может кто-нибудь подсказать как изменить дизайн значков класса, интерфейса, enam?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая система? На виндовс оно само так выглядит. Ну или в новых версиях идеи иконки поменяли.

Comment: Windows Pro 10. Да, пришлось установить идею заново, а сохранить настройки как-то не подумалось. В новой идее значки изменили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно выключить New UI. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, дружище. Это сработало!